# Why is one of these two calculations with eigenvalues faster than the other?

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue

I want to find the eigenvalues of a square matrix. I try 2 different approaches.

```
import numpy as np 
D = np.random.random((500,500))
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(D)
```

```
%timeit np.linalg.eigvals(D)
129 ms ± 7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
%timeit eigenvectors@D@np.linalg.inv(eigenvectors)
42.2 ms ± 4.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Why is the second approach faster? Wasn't the `eigvals` algorithm supposed to be faster because it is well optimized? What do I miss? Also hypothetically we know the eigenvector and we do not need to calculate it.

Comment: I think the first approach has to calculate the eigenvectors as the only input is D, the second is given eigenvectors for free.

Comment: But the eigvals use QR algorithm who has O(n^3) complexity, the same complexity the multiplication of matrices has. So why it is faster? Am I wrong?

Comment: Complexity is a funny thing - it only tells you how something scales, not how long it takes. Iterating through a list is O(n), as is iterating through a list sleeping 1 second after each element.

Comment: 'well optimized' - how do you know that?

Comment: Because numpy is built on top of efficient numerical libraries like LAPACK and BLAS, which provide highly optimized routines for linear algebra computations. Do you think otherwise?

Comment: `@` also uses BLAS  and `inv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But those 2 codes do totally different things.

The 1st one (the 1st you timeit) just computes eigenvalues, without using the fact that you already computed them 1 line earlier.

The 2nd one does not really compute eigen values, but computes the diagonal matrix (but fails to do so, because you inverted the computation order. `np.linalg.inv(eigenvectors) @ D @ eigenvectors` is the diagonal matrix (whose diagonal is indeed made of eigen values). You probably saw this code in an example where `D` is the diagonal matrix (as its name suggests) and then your code computes the original matrix back.
And that computation assumes that eigenvectors are known.

So, even if the 2nd one was a way to compute eigenvalues (a convoluted way, I think, to compute a whole diagonal matrix to get just the values), it would be a way that requires that you compute the eigen vectors first (and to do that, you probably need to compute eigen values too; at least I know no efficient algorithm that computes eigenvectors without also computing eigenvalues. That is why numpy has a `eigvals` method, that computes only eigenvalues, and a `eig` method that computes both eigen values and vectors,  but no `eigvec` method, that would compute only eigen vectors: that would be pointless; why having a method that does less and cost as much as `eig`?

So, another way to put is, is that if you want to compare the timing, you should add the the 2nd timing what it cost you to compute `eigenvectors`. On my PC (apparently approx twice slower than yours), I need 277 ms to compute `eigvals`, and 120 ms to compute the diagonal matrix from `eigenvectors` to which you must add the 360 ms I needed to compute `eigenvectors` in the first place.

So in total, it is 277 ms for `eigvals` vs 480 ms for `eig`+`P@D@P⁻¹`

Comment: The matrix D is just a dense matrix. You are correct about np.linalg.inv(eigenvectors) @ D @ eigenvectors . I was miswritten it. I just want to figure out if I have some simultaneously diagonalizable matrices that have the same eigenvectors but different eigenvalues if it is faster to simply calculate the eigenvector matrix and use P⁻¹@D@P to find the eigenvalues of the other matrices or use the np.linalg.eigvals for each matrix.

Comment: @ABZANMASTER So, what you say is that your problem is not the general one (find eigenvalues), but a very specific one: in the (in my view, strange) case when you know the eigenvectors, but not the eigenvalues, then, how come that 3nd method is faster than 1st. Answer is the same as the one given: the 2nd method does benefit from this strange situation (eigenvectors are known, but not eigenvalues), while 1st doesn't.

Comment: @ABZANMASTER But in that case, it would be even faster to simply compute D@Vᵢ and divide it by Vᵢ to get the ith eigenvalue, where Vᵢ is the ith eigenvector. Or, using matrix multiplication (which is just a bunch of vector multiplication), in numpy, compute `(D@eigenvectors)/eigenvectors)[0]` (the `[0]` part, is just to get the list only once, since in is repeated for each dimension... well except for 0 values, but there has to be a non-zero value in an eigenvector, else it is not an eigenvector by definition)

Comment: @ABZANMASTER Or something in the line of `(D@eigenvectors).max(axis=0)/eigenvectors.max(axis=0)`. Well, it needs some polishing, but on your example, it works well, and computes 5 times faster than the `np.linalg.inv(eigenvectors) @ D @ eigenvectors`

Comment: @ABZANMASTER The general idea, if you know the eigenvectors but the the eigenvalue, is just that if V is an eigenvector of matrix M, then `M@V` is `λV` by definition, and λ is what you are searching for. So just compute `M@V` and compare to V. And no need to compare all components: it is a given that V is an eigenvector in your case, so we already know that `M@V` is `λV`. We just don't know which λ. So, naturally, there is way less computation needed that to compute the diagonal matrix.